# How do I parse a RestSharp response into a class?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to handle sending emails and I need to be able to check the response to make sure everything went okay.

I know absolutely nothing about JSON but what I've seen from my searching has lead me to believe that calling `client.Execute<T>( Foo )` should result in me getting an object of type `T` with properties populated by the result of the request execution...

This is not the case.

In the case where I intentionally fail the POST I get this from the response.Content property :

```
{"error":3,"message":"Wrong credentials specified"}
```

When I submit the request with the proper credentials, response.Content looks like this :

```
{"message":"OK"}
```

which lead me to believe creating a class like this should be all that I would need :

```
public class RestMessage {
    string error { get; set; }
    string message { get; set; }
}
```

but when I call

```
IRestResponse<RestMessage> Foo = Bar.Execute<RestMessage>( Baz );
```

`Foo.Data` equals an object of type `RestMessage`, but in either case the result is always that `error = null` ( which makes sense in the latter case, but not in the former ) and `message = null`.

Clearly it is not as simple as every example I have read makes it out to be.

I have installed RestSharp from NuGet in VS2015 Community using their awesome NuGet... thingy so I have the most recent version.

Can someone explain how I can accomplish what I am trying to do to me as if I were still teething?

Comment: It should be, that's the right way to use it, check the response content when "message" is null from the RestResponse.Content, there should be some small difference on your class vs the json object

Comment: Ehmm, not sure if that could be the case, but try to make the properties public...

Comment: @Gusman Oh man if that's it I'm going to go to bed -.-;

Comment: @Gusman Yep... that was it. I am so done. I hate myself.

Comment: XD, at least you will sleep tonight peacefully

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Gusman for pointing this out.

The answer was so simple I hate myself for not seeing it, and there is now a face-shaped indentation in my desk, and a desk-shaped indentation where my face used to be...

Before :

```
public class RestMessage{
    string error{ get; set; }
    string message{ get; set; }
}
```

After :

```
public class RestMessage{
    public string error{ get; set; }
    public string message{ get; set; }
}
```

Don't drink and code kids...

Comment: your answer made me smile :)